# ASP.NET MVC. Autofac and multiple connection strings

Tags: c#, autofac

I need to use multiple connections string in my ASP.NET MVC application. How I can to do it? Now i'm registering connection as following:

```
builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>().WithParameter(
    "connectionString",
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .ExternallyOwned();

builder.Register(c => new ContextDataContext(c.Resolve<SqlConnection>())).InstancePerDependency();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register multiple instances of a given type by name:

From Autofac tutorial:

```
builder.Register<OnlineState>().Named<IDeviceState>("online");
```

To retrieve a named service, the ResolveNamed() method is used:

```
var r = container.ResolveNamed<IDeviceState>("online");
```

http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

Comment: Thank you. You gave me entry point, and I decide to use Keyed method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is to create your own connection factory, and register it with autofac.
Something like:

```
interface IConnectionFactory{
   SqlConnection CreateConnection(string connectionStringName);
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help with using multiple connection strings? Using a factory makes sense when there is need for custom initialization of components prior to its use. It's not an answer for the core question even if it's helpful. (or I don't see how you plan to use it)

Comment: @kubal5003, his factory will create a connection with a specified connection string, based on its name, so his code can call this factory method to get the needed connection.

Answer (score -3):

You can define multiple connection strings in  section in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="ProductConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="_YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_1_"/>

    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="_YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_2_"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

In your code you can use like,

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductConnection"]` to get the connection string.

In case you want to get an instance based on connection string, you can use any factory which can resolve your instance based on connection string name. **SimpleFactory + Unity** or **SimpleFactory + Autofac** can help you in this.